# Paypal API - Returning failed recurring account transactions

Tags: php, paypal

I was wondering if there was a way to return a list of failed recurring account transactions.

I have a client who wants to have the actual list embedded on his site and doesn't want to have to log into the dashboard every single time.

I have looked all through the API yet I cannot find anything about it.

A good direction on where to look would really help as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any API that will return those directly, but you could use [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) to save details about recurring payments / profiles.

Any time a new profile is created or a payment is completed, skipped, failed, etc. you would get an IPN for that transaction.  Within your IPN script you can save details to your database and then pull from your own database to display the data however you need.

Comment: It's going to take some elbow grease, but I'll get it done. Thank you!

Comment: This is pretty old now, but my [IPN template](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-ipn-template) will get you up and running with data saved in MySQL very quick and easy.  You could easily pull from that to generate reports of any kind.  If you happen to be working with WordPress, I also have [PayPal IPN for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-ipn/) that might interest you.